# GitLab account blocked while changing the username. How do I unblock it?

Tags: gitlab, account, blocked

I wanted to change my username on GitLab so I followed the following procedure:

1. Navigate to your profile's Settings > Account.
2. Enter a new username under Change username.
3. Click Update username.

After clicking on update nothing seem to change so I refreshed the page and I receive the following error:
**Your account has been blocked. Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is an error.**

How do I unblock my account?

PS: I opened a GitLab SaaS account

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/your-account-has-been-blocked-via-git-pull-clone-using-ssh-on-12-9-1-floss-self-managed/35781/26) mentions

> Check `<external_url>/admin/application_settings/general > expand Sign-up Restrictions`, and verify if the checkbox for `Send confirmation email on sign-up` is checked or unchecked?
>
> Having that setting enabled will send a confirmation email, and for that user to be “unlocked”, it requires the confirmation link in the confirmation email is clicked.
>
> If you’re creating a user with Ansible and the confirmation email isn’t received and the link it contains clicked, it would cause the “user is blocked” error you’re seeing.
>
> If you did not check the box for this requirement, I suspect the default setting might’ve changed in 12.9.x. Do you notice if this checkbox was checked before upgrading?
>
> Unchecking the box, or manually “confirming” the email of your Ansible-created user in the GitLab Admin UI should remove the block on this user.

In your case, since you are changing the user manually, see if:

- the IP is blocked (try from another network/device)
- if you have an IDE opened with a GitLab repository accessed through HTTPS: the IDE might need to refresh the Git repository state periodically, and would be using the old credentials (old username).

---

The [OP goutam thakur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16143416/goutam-thakur) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726890/gitlab-account-blocked-while-changing-the-username-how-do-i-unblock-it/71727017#comment126899898_71727017):

> My account was unblocked after I submitted a request through the form "[Gitlab.com (SaaS) user accounts and login issues](https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000803379)".

Comment: Didn't work. Still, my account is blocked.

Comment: @goutamthakur If this is gitlab.com, that would be cause for a support ticket in https://forum.gitlab.com/c/how-to-use-gitlab/7 or https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new. Actually, it would be: https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000803379

Comment: My account was unblocked after I submitted a request through this link https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000803379. Thanks @Vonc

Comment: @goutamthakur Great news! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.